# Disabling copy/paste on Mac

Tags: macos

I have a folder with multiple files under git that I don't want others to copy/paste since there is sensitive info on it. How would I do it in OSX? Disabling copying via AirDrop would be nice as well.

Comment: "I don't want others to copy/paste since there is sensitive info on i" If it is that sensitive then why do others have access?

Comment: Rethink your security policy. First, reduce the number of admins to one. Until you do that, any other admin can undo anything at all that you do.

Comment: Without revealing too many details, I'm working on software development with other people, so obviously others have access to it.

Comment: You need to add any salient information to your question. The point remains, that any admin can undo any policy any other admin sets.